# Reading values during entity values update?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I feel like this must have been answered somewhere and I'm just not querying for it right, so I'll apologize in advance.

I've got a method that takes hundreds of objects from a service and maps them to the database using the code first approach. Right now I'm adding all the objects to the context, one by one, and then saving once at the end. At only 100 it takes about 22 seconds to populate. So, really, I think I have two questions now...

1. If the context were to be updated and someone was trying to access that data (ie: A page that populates content from those tables.), would it be inaccessible? Or would it just grab the data in a read-only fashion? I don't have to worry about conflicting updates, only a read probability, so I'd assume the latter but wanted to check.
2. Is it better to populate and save all at once, or to save after each object gets added?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How a consumer gets the data depends on what locking mechanism they use to access the database. They can choose the default which will wait for all of the objects to be updated, or they can choose to get something in a read-only fashion.

Deciding on whether to update all at once or bit by bit depends on the tradeoff between how long you hold your locks and how much time you want to waste starting new connections. **My** guess would be that 22 seconds of DB write time is too much, so you may want to split up that workload.

However on the other hand 22 seconds for 100 objects sounds like an long time, so you may have some performance problems slowing that down.

Answer (score 0):

This might answer some of your questions:

[Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework)

According to the tests there, it is much better to save all at once. Try turning off the AutoDetectChanges in the DbContext. You should see a small performance benefit.

Just an aside - entity framework is not great at bulk inserts. Consider using regular ADO.Net to do this work.